# glDrawElements and flat shading

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

Is it possible to achieve flat shading in OpenGL when using glDrawElements to draw objects, and if so how? The ideal way would be to calculate a normal for each triangle only once, if possible.

The solution must only use the programmable pipeline (core profile).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are indeed ways around this without duplicating vertices, with some limitations for each one (at least those I can think of with my limited OpenGL experience).

I can see two solutions that would give you a constant value for the normal over each triangle :

- declare the input as `flat` in your shader and pick which vertex gives its value via [glProvokingVertex](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glProvokingVertex.xml); fast but you'll get the normal for one vertex as the normal for the whole triangle, which might not look right
- use a geometry shader taking triangles and outputing triangles to calculate a single normal per face. This is the most flexible way, allowing you to control the resulting effect, but it might be slow (and required geometry shader capable hardware, obviously)

Comment: does glProvokingVertex allow me to only store one normal per triangle?

Comment: @Arne: I am no expert, so others can correct me if I am wrong, but I dont think its possible. There is no such thing as triangle attributes. You have to instead derive it from the vertex attributes in the geometry shader.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the only way to do that is to duplicate all your vertices, since attributes are per-vertex and not per-triangle

When you think about it, this is what we did in immediate mode...